# Entity Framework 4.0 with Sql Compact Edition 4.0 performance issue

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I have a web application with a EF model which I originally designed using a SQL Server 2008 backend. Later on, I decided to use SQL CE for portability, so I converted the model to target Sql CE 4.0. However, I am running into serious performance issues when running this app.

For example, I have a portion in code that retrieves an entity from the database:

```
        Trace.Write("Retrieving node from database", "Application");
        var name = value.ToString();
        var node = DataContext.Entities.Nodes
            .SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == name);
        Trace.Write("Node retrieved from database ", "Application");
```

When I look at the trace information (trace.axd), those lines of code take a wooping 0.6 seconds!!

Trace Information

```
Category       Message                         From First(s)    From Last(s)
Application Retrieving node from database   0.00057591118424269 0.000576
Application Node retrieved from database    0.595122564460008   0.594547
```

And this happens everywhere in my application where I query by Name.

Any ideas? I'm guessing I have to define an index on the column, but how would I do that in the EF model?

**EDIT :** Gramma
**EDIT 2:** Spelling in Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a sample with some performance advice here, using global.asax: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/entity-framework-with-sql-server.html and other performance tips here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/03/15/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-tips.aspx

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, the suggestion by @ErikEJ to add `connection.Open()` to `Application_Start()` helped out a lot! Eventually, I added a condition to check whether the application is using SqlCe: `
            if (((EntityConnection)DataContext.Entities.Connection).StoreConnection.GetType().Name == "SqlCeConnection")
                DataContext.Entities.Connection.Open();`

Comment: I Had the same problem and the connection.Open() helper solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the older versions of SQL CE in the past, and I've found that one major bottleneck is opening the connection.

You might try managing the open connection on your own, and passing it into the data context by hand (rather than allowing the context to automatically manage the connection.)

Comment: hmm, interesting... Now, my current intention is to allow this app to switch to SQL Server anytime (by changing the connection string). How would the application be affected in such a case?

Comment: You would just need to make sure you close any open connections before opening a new connection to the other source.